# Testing if user is allow with a function (not an annotation)

Tags: playframework, deadbolt, deadbolt-2

I want to test permissions of a user in my controller, but I need the name of the permission to change at runtime (sometime it is "projectWrite", sometime "userWrite"...), but annotation need a constant, so I can't use it.

I need to use a function, but I don't know how to ask for the authorisation via function. How to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `be.objectify.deadbolt.core.DeadboltAnalyzer`.

Comment: Hi Steve, is it possible to check a Dynamic restriction in the same way? I couldn't find it on `be.objectify.deadbolt.core.DeadboltAnalyzer`

Comment: `Dynamic` works purely on what you define in  your `DynamicResourceHandler`s - there's no built-in implementation.